# which architectures is important on Android

Tags: android

I have a third party library that provides the files for diff architectures like x86/arm and several others

Where can I find or which library can I remove to decrease used space of my apps.

My apps support 4.0.3 and up.

Architectures library:

1. armabi
2. armabi-v7a
3. arm64-v8a
4. mips
5. mips64
6. x86
7. x86_64

Is it possible to remove their library and support their Arch even if I have removed 1 of those?

Comment: Why not check the statistics page on the google play developer console to see which devices are the most common among your users, and then look up which architecture those devices are based on? ARM-based Android devices are by far the most common (armeabi is outdated, armeabi-v7a is probably the most common, arm64-v8a is becoming more common but those devices should be able to use armeabi-v7a libraries). Many x86-based devices can use armeabi/armeabi-v7a libraries through emulation. MIPS-based devices are pretty much non-existent.